# Can I configure`ts-node` when using `webpack-dev-server`?

Tags: typescript, webpack-dev-server, ts-node

My project structure is like this

```
.
└── my-app/
    ├── .configs/
    │   ├── tsconfig.json
    │   ├── webpack.merge.ts
    │   ├── webpack.dev.config.ts
    │   └── webpack.prod.config.ts
    ├── node_modules
    ├── src/
    │   └── index.tsx
    └── package.json
```

I am have installed `ts-node` and `webpack-dev-server`. When I run `npm start` I get typescript errors because I suspect `ts-node` is linting the webpack configuration:

`error TS7006: Parameter 'env' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

How can I configure the `webpack-dev-server` settings to use the configuration file `.configs/tsconfig.json` when running `ts-node`? I there an option that I am missing in the `"start"` command that can be passed down to `ts-node`?

`package.json`

```
...
"start": "webpack serve --config ./.configs/.webpack.merge.ts --mode=development",
...
```

`webpack.merge.ts`

```
import webpackMerge from 'webpack-merge';
import devConfig from './webpack.dev.config';
import prodConfig from './webpack.prod.config';


export default (env, arg) => {
  const envConfig = arg.mode === 'production'
    ? prodConfig
    : devConfig;

  return webpackMerge({}, envConfig);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer goes on the heels of [Can I set a typescript configuration `tsconfig.json` path on the VSCode IDE to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625074/can-i-set-a-typescript-configuration-tsconfig-json-path-on-the-vscode-ide-to-u)

If you follow the solution posted there then `ts-node` will read the `tsconfig.json` at the root.