# Can I set a typescript configuration `tsconfig.json` path on the VSCode IDE to use?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I have a project structure like the following:

```
.
└── my-app/
    ├── .configs/
    │   ├── tsconfig.json
    │   ├── webpack.merge.ts
    │   ├── webpack.dev.config.ts
    │   └── webpack.prod.config.ts
    ├── node_modules
    ├── src/
    │   └── index.tsx
    └── package.json
```

Running TypeScript on the commandline `tsc --project .configs/tsconfig.json` compiles without issues. But VSCode IDE shows me errors/warnings in the `.tsx`. I don't want to disable TS Warnings so this won't work for me: [How to disable TypeScript warnings in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632215/how-to-disable-typescript-warnings-in-vscode), [Why does VS Code throw "Cannot find module 'typescript'. ts(2307)" while the module is there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412786/why-does-vs-code-throw-cannot-find-module-typescript-ts2307-while-the-mod)

Is there a setting in VSCode that I set a path so that VSCode IDE TypeScript can use for the current project. I understand that if I put the `tsconfig.json` in the root dir (`my-app`) VSCode IDE works as expected. But I would like to keep all configuration scripts in a single folder instead of the root dir. Does VSCode allow for this?

Comment: `tsconfig.json` normally stays [in the root directory of your project](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). It applies to all source files in the same directory and in the subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, VS Code (or more precisely, the built-in TS extension) doesn't support having your config any other place.

What you could do is placing a `tsconfig.json` in your root that [extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) your `.config/tsconfig.json`. It's not the prettiest, but you can make it pretty seamless by 1) adding it to your `.git/info/exclude` to make git ignore it (without having to modify `.gitignore`) and 2) adding it to your `Files: Exclude` VS Code option to hide it from your explorer in VS Code.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57948466/836701 to enable `IntelliSense` for a particular folder in your project you can have a `tsconfig.json` in that folder and open it as a part of your workspace via `File -> Add Folder to Workspace…`. So in your case you can create `tsconfig.base.json` or just `tsconfig.json` in your project root and then create a `tsconfig.json` in `src/` folder which extends your root `tsconfig.json`. So `VSCode` will run `IntelliSense` for `src/` with  `tsconfig.json` inside it. In result errors and warnings will disappear.

Comment: This does work, but keep in mind that you cannot add `files` individually to VSCode workspaces. So if you want to track a `readme.md` on your project root, workspaces are a non-starter.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings in vscode and search to
`TypeScript › Preferences: Import Module Specifier` then choose the `non-relative` option.